# Is it possible to find uncertainties of spaCy POS tags?

Tags: python, nlp, spacy, spell-checking

I am trying to build a non-English spell checker that relies on classification of sentences by spaCy, which allows my algorithm to then use the POS tags and the grammatical dependencies of the individual tokens to determine incorrect spelling (in my case more specifically: incorrect splits in Dutch compound words).

However, spaCy appears to classify sentences incorrectly if they contain grammatical errors, for example classifying a noun as a verb, even though the classified word doesn't even look like a verb.

Because of this I'm wondering if it is possible to obtain the uncertainties of spaCy's classification, to make it possible to tell if spaCy is struggling with a sentence. After all, if spaCy is struggling with a classification, that would provide my spell checker with more confidence that the sentence contains errors.

Is there any way to know whether spaCy thinks a sentence is grammatically correct (without having to specify patterns of all correct sentence structures in my language), or to obtain classification certainties?

---

Edit, based on suggestions in the comments by @Sergey Bushmanov:

I found https://spacy.io/api/tagger#predict, which might be useful to get the probabilities for the tags. However, I'm not really sure what I am looking at, and I'm not really following what the docs mean about the output. I'm using the following code:

```
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
text = "This is an example sentence for the Spacy tagger."
doc = nlp(text)

docs = nlp(text, disable=['tagger'])
scores, tensors = nlp.tagger.predict([docs])

print(scores)
probs = tensors[0]
for p in probs:
    print(p, max(p), p.tolist().index(max(p)))
```

This prints what I am guessing is some integer representations of the predictions (considering that 'integer' and 'representation' get the same scores), and then an array of 96 floats for every word in the sentence. It also lists the highest score and the position of that highest score, but it seems like for most words, there are multiple items in the `p` array that get a similar value. Now I'm wondering what these arrays mean, and how to extract probabilities for each classification from it.

---

The question is: How can I interpret this output to get the specific probabilities for specific tags found by spaCy's tagger? Or another way to put this same question is: What does the output generated by the above code mean?

Comment: You may wish to check how one can extract probabilities for ner tags https://support.prodi.gy/t/accessing-probabilities-in-ner/94/2 . I suspect assessing pos probabilities may be similar. Please post back if you find an answer to your question!

Comment: @SergeyBushmanov I have looked into it for a bit and I noticed that there is a `nlp.entity.beam_parse` method, as well as `nlp.parser.beam_parse`, but apparently for the thing I want to analyse, there isn't a similar method `nlp.tagger.beam_parse`. Do you know where I might find more resources that might help me find a way to apply this same approach to the tagger?

Comment: @SergeyBushmanov I've edited my question to include some code that attempts to use https://spacy.io/api/tagger#predict to achieve the desired result. I'm not really following the output of spacy's tagger predictions, however. Could you help with that?

Comment: It must be `doc = nlp(text); scores, tensors = nlp.tagger.predict([doc])`,  I suspect these are just keys for pos'. Still not probabilities

Comment: For those suggesting to close this question it would be nice it they share the reason for doing so. So that the question has a chance to be adjusted accordingly.

Comment: @SergeyBushmanov I've edited my question again with some updated code, but I'm still not really certain what the output of this code means. It does seem like the tensors are indeed arrays that contain probabilities, but I have no idea what these probabilities refer to.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225741/discussion-between-sergey-bushmanov-and-joeytje50).

Answer (score 4):

```py
>>> nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
>>> tagger = nlp.get_pipe("tagger")
>>> doc = nlp("Turn left")
>>> tagger.model.predict([doc])[0][1]
array([2.4706091e-07, 9.5889463e-06, 7.8214543e-07, 1.0063847e-06,
       1.4711081e-07, 8.9995199e-05, 1.3229882e-05, 1.7524673e-07,
       1.8464769e-05, 2.4248957e-06, 1.2176755e-06, 3.3774859e-07,
       1.3199920e-06, 1.2011193e-06, 9.4455345e-06, 2.1991875e-05,
       1.6732251e-02, 1.3964747e-07, 2.0764594e-07, 7.0467541e-07,
       1.4303426e-07, 3.7962508e-07, 1.2130551e-03, 3.1479198e-07,
       4.8646534e-08, 6.1310317e-07, 1.0607551e-05, 3.7493783e-06,
       2.7809198e-08, 1.2118652e-05, 9.9081490e-03, 1.8219554e-06,
       4.7322575e-07, 1.8754436e-05, 6.2416703e-08, 9.5453437e-08,
       1.8937490e-05, 6.3916352e-03, 3.7999314e-01, 1.5741379e-03,
       5.8360571e-01, 9.6441705e-05, 1.7456010e-04, 5.1820080e-06,
       1.2672864e-06, 9.7453121e-06, 2.4000105e-05, 5.1192428e-06,
       2.4821245e-05], dtype=float32)
>>> r = [*enumerate(tagger.model.predict([doc])[0][1])]
>>> r.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
>>> r
[(28, 2.7809198e-08), (24, 4.8646534e-08), (34, 6.24167e-08), (35, 9.545344e-08), (17, 1.3964747e-07), (20, 1.4303426e-07), (4, 1.4711081e-07), (7, 1.7524673e-07), (18, 2.0764594e-07), (0, 2.470609e-07), (23, 3.1479198e-07), (11, 3.377486e-07), (21, 3.7962508e-07), (32, 4.7322575e-07), (25, 6.1310317e-07), (19, 7.046754e-07), (2, 7.8214543e-07), (3, 1.0063847e-06), (13, 1.2011193e-06), (10, 1.2176755e-06), (44, 1.2672864e-06), (12, 1.319992e-06), (31, 1.8219554e-06), (9, 2.4248957e-06), (27, 3.7493783e-06), (47, 5.119243e-06), (43, 5.182008e-06), (14, 9.4455345e-06), (1, 9.588946e-06), (45, 9.745312e-06), (26, 1.0607551e-05), (29, 1.2118652e-05), (6, 1.3229882e-05), (8, 1.8464769e-05), (33, 1.8754436e-05), (36, 1.893749e-05), (15, 2.1991875e-05), (46, 2.4000105e-05), (48, 2.4821245e-05), (5, 8.99952e-05), (41, 9.6441705e-05), (42, 0.0001745601), (22, 0.0012130551), (39, 0.001574138), (37, 0.006391635), (30, 0.009908149), (16, 0.016732251), (38, 0.37999314), (40, 0.5836057)]
```

You see here the top 2 matches (at the end of the list) (38, 0.37999314), (40, 0.5836057) don't have a high confidence (~50%) so you have some indication of the ambiguity.

```
>>> tagger.labels
('$', "''", ',', '-LRB-', '-RRB-', '.', ':', 'ADD', 'AFX', 'CC', 'CD', 'DT', 'EX', 'FW', 'HYPH', 'IN', 'JJ', 'JJR', 'JJS', 'LS', 'MD', 'NFP', 'NN', 'NNP', 'NNPS', 'NNS', 'PDT', 'POS', 'PRP', 'PRP$', 'RB', 'RBR', 'RBS', 'RP', 'SYM', 'TO', 'UH', 'VB', 'VBD', 'VBG', 'VBN', 'VBP', 'VBZ', 'WDT', 'WP', 'WP$', 'WRB', 'XX', '``')
>>> tagger.labels[40]
'VBN'
>>> tagger.labels[38]
'VBD'
```

Looks like there is some language-specific tagging, and some mapping is required to get to universal POS tags.