# Is it possible to find uncertainties of spaCy token dependencies?

Tags: python, nlp, dependencies, spacy, part-of-speech

I am using spaCy in order to match text against certain dependency patterns. I'm facing the problem that my DependencyParser gives different results even in simple sentences when a single word (of same ground-true POS-Tag) is changed. E.g. 'The baker and supervisor support the baking' finds that 'support' is a VERB, 'baker' and 'supervisor' are NOUNS. 'baker' and 'supervisor' have nsubj dependency to support, 'baking' is dobj of support. [See here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cfjgr.png). Now changing this to 'The baker and oven support the baking' results in an ADV POS-Tag for 'oven' instead of NOUN and has dependency advmod to 'support'. [See here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EtW98.png). This makes absolutely no sense as oven is never an adverb. I thought that the DependencyParser probably uses the POS-Tags and that changing them could change the resulting dependencies.
I found this question [3] and managed to extract the probabilities of all POS-Tags for each token with `Tagger.model.predict([doc])` which delivers a matrix of shape len(doc) x len(tagger.labels). In the first sentence 'supervisor' got 99,8 % for NOUN, while 'oven' only got 62 % for ADV. So I produced multiple docs for the same text, where I changed the Token.pos_ to the second and third most probable candidates if there is uncertainty (most probable tag < 90 %). I then ran the DependencyMatcher with all three docs, thinking that the different POS-Tags would lead to a change in dependencies, but it doesn't. When 'oven' has POS-Tag NOUN (third most probable tag) it still has advmod dependency with 'support', which doesn't make sense.
So similar to [3] I want to inspect the probabilities of all values for Token.dep_ for each token in the doc. Unfortunately, `DependencyParser.model.predict([doc])` doesn't deliver this (afaik).

[3] [Is it possible to find uncertainties of spaCy POS tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65218606/is-it-possible-to-find-uncertainties-of-spacy-pos-tags)